# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: android, sockets, http, udp, timeout

I'm developing my application on a Samsung Galaxy S which I've upgraded to Android 4.2. The application run normally on this device.

When I test it on a phone which is running Android 2.2, an exception occurs.

I check it again and again，I find that the problem happen after the application sends a UDP  DatagramPacket.

The problem never happen when I comment the code referring to sending UDP DatagramPacket.

Could anyone please tell me what‘s the reason why? How to solve the problem?

Main method：

```
 public static String getDataFromServerInPostMethod(String url,
        String content) {
    HttpURLConnection httpurlconnection = null;

    String result = "";
    try {
        InputStream stream = null;
        // String host = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();
        // if (host != null) {
        // int port = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();
        // SocketAddress vAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        // java.net.Proxy vProxy = new java.net.Proxy(
        // java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, vAddress);
        // httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
        // .openConnection(vProxy);
        // } else {
        // httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
        // .openConnection();
        // }
        httpurlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url)
                .openConnection();
        httpurlconnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpurlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        httpurlconnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
        httpurlconnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT * 1000);
        try {
            httpurlconnection.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httpurlconnection.connect();
        MyLog.e(TAG, "getURL:" + httpurlconnection.getURL());
        httpurlconnection.getOutputStream().write(content.getBytes());
        httpurlconnection.getOutputStream().flush();
        httpurlconnection.getOutputStream().close();
        stream = httpurlconnection.getInputStream();
        result = SystemUtil.convertStreamToString(stream);
        if (httpurlconnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            MyLog.w(TAG,
                    "Responsed-->>getURL:" + httpurlconnection.getURL());
        } else {
            MyLog.e(TAG,
                    "not Responsed,ResponseCode:"
                            + httpurlconnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (httpurlconnection != null) {
            httpurlconnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Post your code and your logcat error please.

Comment: Main method added! Please take a look firstly!

Comment: Where is it crashing? Post your logcat errors so we can help you.

Comment: when running to "httpurlconnection.connect();",it got execption :java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```